# mysqli error - killing me

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This few lines of code gives me x errors, and I am killing myself for question. Can someone with fresh eyes look into it and point me to answer.

Error: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli.

Lines with errors: 3, 4, 9, 10

```
function mysqli_query_excute( $sql )
{
    global $link;

    $result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );

    if(  ! $result )
    {
        die( printf( "Error: %s\n", mysqli_error( $link ) ) );
    }

    return $result->fetch_object();
}
```

this is the whole thing:

```
<?php

    global $link;
    $link = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx" )
    or die("Couldnt connect");


function mysqli_query_excute( $sql )
{
    global $link;

    $result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );

    if(  ! $result )
    {
        die( printf( "Error: %s\n", mysqli_error( $link ) ) );
    }

    return $result->fetch_object();
}

    /*
    * get the user data from database by email and password
    **/
    function get_user_by_email_and_password( $email, $password )
    {
        return mysqli_query_excute( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'" );
    }

    /*
    * get the user data from database by provider name and provider user id
    **/
    function get_user_by_provider_and_id( $provider_name, $provider_user_id )
    {
        return mysqli_query_excute( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE hybridauth_provider_name = '$provider_name' AND hybridauth_provider_uid = '$provider_user_id'" );
    }

    /*
    * get the user data from database by provider name and provider user id
    **/
    function create_new_hybridauth_user( $email, $first_name, $last_name, $provider_name, $provider_user_id )
    {
        // let generate a random password for the user
        $password = md5( str_shuffle( "0123456789abcdefghijklmnoABCDEFGHIJ" ) );

        mysqli_query_excute(
            "INSERT INTO users
            (
                email,
                password,
                first_name,
                last_name,
                hybridauth_provider_name,
                hybridauth_provider_uid,
                created_at
            )
            VALUES
            (
                '$email',
                '$password',
                '$first_name',
                '$last_name',
                $provider_name,
                $provider_user_id,
                NOW()
            )"
        );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please post your query.

Comment: function get_user_by_email_and_password( $email, $password )
    {
     return mysqli_query_excute( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'" );
    }

Comment: Please post your $sql query

Answer (score -1):

This error is killing me too. In clear English it says that $link is not a mysqli instance, as it should be.

So, you have to connect to mysqli first.

Comment: $link = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx" );

Answer (score -1):

Can it be what you forget make $link global before you connect to database ?

```
   global $link;
   $link = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx" );
```

Comment: This was the case, but there are still errors now on lines 5 and 9

Comment: Check your connection, are you really connect to mysql ? :) and paste errors please.

Comment: [Sun Sep 13 12:14:09.688128 2015] [:error] [pid 21275] [client 86.58.36.76:39907] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/sh6866/domains/odvoz-vozil.si/public_html/test/login.php on line 88, referer: http://odvoz-vozil.si/test/login.php
[Sun Sep 13 12:14:09.688187 2015] [:error] [pid 21275] [client 86.58.36.76:39907] PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/sh6866/domains/odvoz-vozil.si/public_html/test/login.php on line 92, referer: http://odvoz-vozil.si/test/login.php

Comment: global $link;
    $link = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx" ) or die("Couldn't connect");

Comment: Hm may be you disconnect from mysql before your query execute ?

Comment: May be what you disconnect from mysql before yours query execute, or you not yet connect to your sql server, try to do next:    `$link = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx" ); $result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );`